# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str Face Recognition

Tags: python, arrays

So I am using code that is supposed to open my webcam and do face recognition, but this is the ou

```
(facecourse-py2) lawn-128-61-17-230:face-recognition-opencv apaar$ 

python recognize_faces_video.py --encodings encodings.pickle --output output/webcam_face_recognition_output.avi --display 1
[INFO] loading encodings...
[INFO] starting video stream...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recognize_faces_video.py", line 60, in <module>
    matches = int(face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

And the code around line 60 looks like this:

```
    for encoding in encodings:
    # attempt to match each face in the input image to our known
    # encodings
    matches = int(face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
        encoding))
    name = "Unknown"
```

Comment: We'll need more info to help you, like what is `data` ?

Comment: What is the type on `data`? It seems like it's telling you it's a string and you're accessing it like a dictionary.

Comment: This is the line where I declare data:

Comment: data = pickle.dumps(open(args["encodings"], "rb").read())

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this question. For one, the indentation is wrong. For another, the traceback is self-explanatory; `data` can only be indexed by numbers, such as `1` or `2`, not strings like `"encodings"`. `data` is probably a list or tuple, not a Pandas dataframe, so indexing on `data` only works with ints.

Comment: If you want to know the `type` of `data`, call `print(type(data))`

Comment: The formatting is correct, I just couldn't get the formatting correct on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

In the comment section you said you initialize `data` as,

```
data = pickle.dumps(open(args["encodings"], "rb").read())
```

This will return a `string` and you try to access it using another `string` like so,

```
data["encodings"]
```

Thus the error.

Comment: I cast it to an int later on and the program works for about 3 seconds and then gives me that error

Comment: What do you cast as a int ?

Comment: this is what i do:

Comment: matches = int(face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
   encoding))

Comment: Yes and as I said in my answer `data["encodings"]` won't work since `data` is a string and you try to access it with another string.